# Hive query or pig script to resolve the below mentioned issue

Tags: hive, apache-pig, hiveql

I have one table with below data:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

output should like

```
AB
AC
AD
AE
BC
BD
BE
CD
CE
DE
```

How to do this in PIG and Hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  concat (t1.col, t2.col)
from    t t1 cross join t t2
where   t1.col < t2.col
```

---

```
+----+
| AB |
| AC |
| AD |
| AE |
| BC |
| BD |
| BE |
| CD |
| CE |
| DE |
+----+
```